# AWS Athena SYNTAX_ERROR: not a valid timestamp literal

Tags: timestamp, amazon-athena, presto

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT startDate
FROM tests
WHERE startDate
    BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '1555248497'
        AND TIMESTAMP '1555248498' limit 10;
```

And keep getting this error message:

```
**"SYNTAX_ERROR: line 4:13: '1555248497' is not a valid timestamp literal"**
```

I've also tried removing the quotation marks around the timestamp, and got the following error:

```
line 4:23: extraneous input '1555248497' expecting {'.', '[', 'at', 'and', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '||'} (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 44ad270d-54e4-442b-8b1a-93a6b6eba9ac)
```

The type of "startedDateTime" column is "timestamp".

How can I cast the timestamp values to a valid timestamp literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`timestamp` literals](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/language/types.html#timestamp) are of the form like this:

```
TIMESTAMP '2001-08-22 03:04:05.321'
```

To convert UNIX timestamp (number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC) to `timestamp` data type, use [`from_unixtime`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#from_unixtime).

Comment: Thanks! the following syntax is working: SELECT *
FROM tests
WHERE startDate
    BETWEEN from_unixtime(1555246800)
        AND from_unixtime(1555249497) limit 10;